# Is there any way to force overscroll glow effect in android?

Tags: java, android, glow, android-overscoll

I am developing an application, in which there are scrollviews.

In the emulator, the overscroll effect is shown, in an HTC Legend it is shown, but in my Samsung Galaxy S2 its not... (I DO have gingebread, with overscroll glow enabled).
I like this effect and I would like to apply it to my application (if the user have 2.3+ of course).
Is there any way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use attribute **android:overScrollMode** in your layouts. Are you using it?

Example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="always">
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize it. Where should I put it?

Comment: For what API level do you develop app? **android:overScrollMode** is availiable from level 9. Or if you use **[Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)**

Comment: Where do I need to put it? and isn't there any other solution to make it work even on level 8? (I mean 2.2- will not see the effect, but android 2.3+ WILL see it)

Comment: I added example in answer. I think it is no way to make it work on level 8 and lower with using only standard API attributes. You need to create your own views (extend and override ScrollView, for example) to make this effect.